# How to connect/link SQL db to Access database using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, database-connection

I have a SQL database that centralizes all data within our agency; however, we also receive data from outside sources that needs to be parsed into our db structure.  One of our partners maintains an Access 2016 database that they provide to us weekly to perform various analyses.  My goal is to build an SSIS (2017) package that will move data from the Access db to SQL tables; replacing the Access db w/ an updated version and re-running the SSIS package on a scheduled basis.

I am trying to set up a connection manager for the Access database, but I cannot find a driver option in the provided DSN list for .accdb files, only .mdb files types, when I try to build the connection string.  How do I create the connection for an Access 2016 database (i.e., .accdb)???

Comment: The Jet 4.0 drivers only understand .mdb files. Have you downloaded and installed the newer Microsoft Access Database Engine redistributables for either [2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255) or [2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)?

Comment: Yes, I got it to work after installing the newer Access Database Engine.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SSIS for something like this.  You can simply export data from MS Access to SQL Server, without replying on another app.

This VBA sample will export data from a table in Access to SQL Server.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim sTblNm As String
Dim sTypExprt As String
Dim sCnxnStr As String, vStTime As Variant
Dim db As Database, tbldef As DAO.TableDef

On Error GoTo ExportTbls_Error

sTypExprt = "ODBC Database" 'Export Type
sCnxnStr = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=your_sever_name" & stServer & ";DATABASE=your_database_name" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"

vStTime = Timer
Application.Echo False, "Visual Basic code is executing."

Set db = CurrentDb()

'need a reference to Microsoft DAO 3.x library
For Each tbldef In db.TableDefs
'Don’t export System and temporary tables
    Debug.Print tbldef.Name
    If tbldef.Name Like "*Table1*" Then
        sTblNm = tbldef.Name
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, sTypExprt, sCnxnStr, acTable, sTblNm, sTblNm
    End If
Next tbldef

MsgBox "Done! Time taken=" & (Timer - vStTime)

On Error GoTo 0
SmoothExit_ExportTbls:
Set db = Nothing
Application.Echo True
Exit Sub

ExportTbls_Error:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ExportTblsODST"
Resume SmoothExit_ExportTbls

End Sub
```

See the link below for more info.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2484/import-data-from-microsoft-access-to-sql-server/